# Showing that the closure of the closure of a set is its closure

Tags: general-topology

I have the feeling I'm missing something obvious, but here it goes...

I'm trying to prove that for a subset $A$ of a topological space $X$, $\overline{\overline{A}}=\overline{A}$.  The inclusion $\overline{\overline{A}} \subseteq \overline{A}$ I can do, but I'm not seeing the other direction.

Say we let $x \in \overline{A}$.  Then every open set $O$ containing $x$ contains a point of $A$.  Now if $x \in \overline{\overline{A}}$, then every open set containing $x$ contains a point of $\overline{A}$ distinct from $x$.  My problem is: couldn't $\{x,a\}$ potentially be an open set containing $x$ and containing a point of $A$, but containing no other point in $\overline{A}$?

(Also, does anyone know a trick to make \bar{\bar{A}} look right?  The second bar is skewed to the left and doesn't look very good.)

Comment: You can try and prove two separate things that will let you conclude that:
$(1)$ $\operatorname{cl} A$ is closed. 
$(2)$ If $A$ is closed, then $\operatorname{cl} A = A$. The fact that ${\operatorname{cl} ({\operatorname{cl} A})}=\operatorname{cl}  A$ then follows at once.

Comment: Isn't $\bar{A} \subseteq \bar{\bar{A}}$ true just because every set is a subset of its closure?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How do you define the closure of a set $A$? If it's not already your definition, it might be a useful thing to prove that the closure of a set is precisely the intersection of all closed sets containing it.

Comment: Which is, the smallest closed set containing it...

Answer (score 4):

The condition you want to check is
\[
x \in \bar A \quad \Leftrightarrow \quad \text{for each open set $U$ containing $x$, $U \cap A \neq \emptyset$}
\]
This definition implies, among other things, that $A \subset \bar A$. Indeed, with the notation above we always have $x \in U \cap A$. Is it clear why this implies the remaining inclusion in your problem?

If you instead require that $U \cap (A - \{x\}) \neq \emptyset$ then you have defined the set $A'$ of [limit points](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_point) of $A$. We have $\bar A = A \cup A'$. Simple examples such as $A = \{0\}$ inside of $\mathbb R$, for which $\bar A = A$ but $A' = \emptyset$, can be helpful in keeping this straight.

Comment: Most topological properties, by the way, have a lot of equivalent forms. Learning the different definitions of the closure [listen on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(topology)#Closure_of_a_set) can really save you work — [Kris' hint](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/173071/3701), for example, would give maybe the quickest proof possible of the inclusion that you already did.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose $x\in\overline{\overline{A}}$. Let $U$ be an open set containing $x$; we want to show that $U\cap A\neq\varnothing$. We know that $U\cap\overline{A}\neq\varnothing$, so there exists $y\in \overline{A}$ such that $y\in U$. But since $U$ is an open set that contains $y$ and $y\in\overline{A}$, then...

Comment: then $\overline{A} = A$?

Comment: Is  $x\in\bar{\bar{A}}?$

Comment: @V.R.M.: Isn't that the first sentence of the post?

Comment: yes it is;  ok sorry for asking about _your_ proof.

Comment: I think 2 or 1 more bars are needed on the rest of the A's.

Comment: @V.R.M. Although it's been almost 10 years since I wrote the above, I believe that you are incorrect. We are trying to show that the closure of the closure is the closure; the only nontrivial inclusion is to show that any $x$ in $\overline{\overline{A}}$ is in $\overline{A}$; that is we want to show that if $U$ is an open set containing $x$, then $x\cap A$ is nonempty, exactly as I wrote. Because $x$ is in the closure of $\overline{A}$, we know that any open set containing $x$ will intersect $\overline{A}$, exactly as I wrote. So, no. There are no bars missing.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin sorry, again :)  (don't be upset :) my mistake.. I don't know what I was thinking

Answer (score 0):

This depends on what is [admissible](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/116035). The closure of a closed set is itself. So just show the closure is closed.

Btw, **remark on Kris's answer**: The fact that closure of closure is closure is the same thing as saying either of these

1. the intersection of all closed sets containing $A$ is equal to the intersection of all closed sets containing $\overline{A}$
2. the intersection of all closed sets containing $A$ is equal to the intersection of all closed sets containing (the intersection of all closed sets containing $A$)

Answer (score -1):

A set is closed iff every **convergent sequence** in the set has its limit in that set. The closure operation adds a set's limit points to the set. A closed set already contains its limit points, so repeating the operation doesn't change the answer (**idempoten**t).

---

For Example:

The sequence 1/n; 0 < n < inf goes like this..

1, 1/2, 1/3, 1/4, ... , 1/465674564, ...

It's limit is 0, which is not part of the sequence, so closure would add the 0.

*NOTE - The above example is just meant to illustrate how closure works.  As far as I know, this sequence is not a subset of any metric space.*

Comment: This answer is wrong from the begining. Sequential closedness is a distinct notion from closedness.